# CNAME map subdomain with NGINX Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, subdomain, cname

I'm used to doing this with Apache & am having issues replicating what I want with NGINX as I'm new to the latter. As I understand it [Server Blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) are more or less the NGINX equivalent of Apache's [VirtualHosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

**What I want:**

Both mapping / serving the same app:

- api.domain1.com
- api.domain2.com

**What I have:**

An Express app & NGINX running on Ubuntu 20.04

- `api.domain1.com` - A record pointing to my IP
- `api.domain1.com` - Serving my app (working just fine)
- `api.domain2.com` - CNAME record pointing to `api.domain1.com`
- `api.domain2.com` - Serving the default `Welcome to nginx!` page

My question(s)

1. Do I have to make a 'server block' for each domain mapped to my app?
2. Can I handle multiple (sub)domains with one A) server block file or B) do I need a server block per (sub)domain

In my server block file I have:

`~/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_api`

```
server {

        root /var/www/my_api/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.domain1.com www.api.domain1.com;

        location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.api.domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = api.domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name api.domain1.com www.api.domain1.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, shortly after I tried the following (simplified a bit for the purposes of example) & it seemed to do the trick. Specifically: adding additional server{} directives to the same file seem to allow serving the same app via multiple (sub)domains.

```
server {

        root /var/www/iris_api/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.domain1.com www.api.domain1.com;

        location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}

server {

        root /var/www/iris_api/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.domain2.com www.api.domain2.com;

        location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```